# RadioButtonFor empiezan ya marcados - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, radiobutton

Saludos estoy trabajando con un quiz en Asp.Net MVC y cuando compilo mi proyecto y voy a las preguntas los `RadioButtonfor` una de las opciones ya vienen seleccionadas y no puedo desmarcarlas. Hay una solución para esto?

Codigo:

```
 <div class="row">


        <div class="container" style="margin:0 auto;margin-top:150px;">

            <div class="row">
                <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TEXTO)</h1>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <h3>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PREGUNTA1, @Model.ID) @Model.PREGUNTA1</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <h3>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PREGUNTA2,  @Model.ID) @Model.PREGUNTA2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h3>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PREGUNTA3,  @Model.ID) @Model.PREGUNTA3</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h3>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PREGUNTA4, @Model.ID) @Model.PREGUNTA4</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RESPUESTA)

            </div>
            <div class="rown">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: a ver si esto te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150401/start-a-group-of-radiobuttons-unchecked-in-asp-net-mvc/7150992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar [CheckboxRadio (no JS)](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/oPgeG) que me gusta y ha usado en mi proyecto sin problema. Con esto `checkbox` se puedo marcar todo/nada. El siguiente es el código relacionado de `CheckboxRadio`:

***Controller (Create):***

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.RolesList = RoleManager.Roles.Select(m => m.Name);
    return PartialView("_Create");
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Exclude = null)] ApplicationGroup 
applicationgroup, params string[] selectedRoles)
{
}
```

***View (Create):***

```
@model Project.Identity.ApplicationGroup

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Roles", new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="" class="" />
                <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                <text id= "checkText">Todo?</text> 
            </label>
        </div>

        @foreach (string role in ViewBag.RolesList)
        {
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRoles" value="@role" class="" />
                    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                    @role
                </label>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    // para marcar todo/nada
    $("#checkAll").change(function () {
        var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', checked);
        $('#checkText').text(checked ? 'Nada?' : 'Todo?');
    }); 
</script>
```

***CSS:***

```
/* Checkbox Styles */ 
.checkbox label:after, .radio label:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.checkbox .cr, .radio .cr {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    border-radius: .25em;
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: .5em;
}

.radio .cr {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .cr .cr-icon, .radio .cr .cr-icon {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
}

.radio .cr .cr-icon {
    margin-left: 0.04em;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"], .radio label input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"] + .cr > .cr-icon, .radio label input[type="radio"] + .cr > .cr-icon {
    transform: scale(3) rotateZ(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .cr > .cr-icon, .radio label input[type="radio"]:checked + .cr > .cr-icon {
    transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + .cr, .radio label input[type="radio"]:disabled + .cr {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Espero que esto ayude...

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero tengo el problema de : cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: De nada amigo. Entonces puedes necesitar estas clases siguientes: `using System.Linq;` y `using System.Data.Entity;`. Podrías tratar con esos otra vez y me informar por favor?